# python cx_oracle read the result of a query from a GUI

Tags: sql, python-3.x, cx-oracle

i have a python code that creates a gui where i make the query using a cursor (=curs) asking from the user to enter a serial number. According to this number the oracle table returns a result (ie 1111111). After that, I want a second query from another table: ‘select project_name from customer_desc where customer_name_d= the value in the customer box(=1111111)'. Any ideas? I need to make a new connection to the base? How can I set the where clause in order to read the textvalue returned to gui text field, with blind variables?
Thanks

```
   import cx_Oracle
   from tkinter import*
   from tkinter import messagebox

   def search():
   try:

    connstr='SOLVATIO/SOLVATIO@localhost'
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("select * from customers where afm='%s'"%afm.get())
    result=curs.fetchone()
    company_name.set(result[1])
    e1.configure(state='disabled')
    conn.close()

    def clear():
   afm.set('')
   company_name.set('')
   e1.configure(state='normal')

   a1=Tk()
   a1.title('SOLVATIO')
   a1.geometry('600x300')
   ptitle=Label(a1, text='''search asset''')
   ptitle.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

   afm=StringVar()
   company_name=StringVar()
   l1=Label (a1, text=' AFM ')
   e1=Entry(a1, textvariable=afm)
   l2=Label (a1, text=' customer ')
   e2=Entry(a1, textvariable=company_name)
   b1=Button(a1, text=' Search ', command=search)
   l1.grid(row=1, column=0)
   e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
   l2.grid(row=2, column=0)
   e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
   b1.grid(row=1, column=2)
   a1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough detail about how you are invoking/running Python to answer (unless someone can guess what %afm is).  On a more important topic you MUST use bind variables instead of the %s string build up, otherwise you have a big security hole and will have poor scalability.  Check out some of the cx_Oracle samples or follow the tutorial: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most of the way there. To use bind variables you need to do the following:

```
curs.execute("select * from customers where afm=:1", [afm.get()])
```

The rest of your code worked as is.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and worked. For the second part of my question, how to put inside my second query the value of the first? i mean, there is any link or suggestions what is the syntax of reading from a gui textbox?

Comment: What second query? The example I gave with customers is reading from a GUI textbox and using the contents as a bind variable...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer because of the ‘afm’ column that I use in my first select. It worked, thanks a lot!!!